# mount command outputs usage on correct arguments

Tags: cyanogenmod, mount, busybox

I enabled root for adb, and then tried the following:

```
root@crespo:/ # mount /dev/block/platform/s3c-sdhci.0/by-name/media /storage/sdcard0
Usage: mount [-r] [-w] [-o options] [-t type] device directory
1|root@crespo:/ # mount /dev/block/mmcblk0p3 /storage/sdcard0
Usage: mount [-r] [-w] [-o options] [-t type] device directory
1|root@crespo:/ # mount /dev/block/mmcblk0 /storage/sdcard0
Usage: mount [-r] [-w] [-o options] [-t type] device directory
```

but, even if `-t` is optional, I get a different error message by adding it:

```
1|root@crespo:/ # mount -t vfat /dev/block/mmcblk0 /storage/sdcard0
mount: Device or resource busy
```

maybe the arguments parsing of the command is messed up... seems like a bug in busybox, or is something much more pedestrian going wrong?

Comment: Check that `/dev/block/mmcblk0` is a device node, and that `/system/sdcard0` exists and is a directory (not a symlink).

Comment: whoops, I realized that the correct target is `/storage/sdcard0` not `/system/sdcard0`... the result is still the same btw

Comment: @DanHulme `stat /dev/block/mmcblk0` says it's a `block special file` and `stat /storage/sdcard0` says it's `directory`

Comment: I also sent a mail to the busybox mailing list: http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/busybox/2014-January/080328.html

Comment: You can't mount mmcblk0, you can only mount partitions (xxxxxxYpZ)

Comment: Don't add extra spaces in commands,it won't work.

Comment: I agree, the argument splitting is done by the shell, busybox sits at a lower level... I'm not sure which kind of shell is running on cyanogenmod, but it was a bit of a leap to assume it'd matter... since the question is clearer without that, I'll remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that mount isn't actually supplied by `busybox`, but by `toolbox`.

With this knowledge, it was easy to track down the cause of the bug: unlike busybox, since I don't have another "toolbox" implementation with a correctly working `mount` command, it's likely that the behavior would've been easy to see from the code.

In fact [the problem is here at line 330](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_system_core/blob/cm-10.2/toolbox/mount.c#L330): it checks if `type == NULL`, but then outputs an `USAGE` that erroneously shows `-t` as optional

Compare with [busybox at line 1930](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_external_busybox/blob/cm-10.2/util-linux/mount.c#L1930): `// Loop through filesystem types until mount succeeds`